# Parse Server Cloud Code Query to Pointer

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

this is the structure of my Database with the classes:

User ->
   objectId (String)
   username (String)

Friends ->
   objectId (String)
   toUser (Pointer <_User> )
   fromUser (Pointer <_User> )

My goal is to retrieve the users with the usernames, which matches the columns toUser and fromUser with a specific Id. The Pointer of toUser and fromUser variable is the objectId of the table "User"

How my query should be?

I tried this one but it doesn`t work

```
Parse.Cloud.define('FriendsQuery', function(req,res) {
const friends = new Parse.Query("Friends");
friends.equalTo("toUser","fEjQgAPvDO");
const userQuery = new Parse.Query("User");    

userQuery.matchesQuery('friend', friends);
userQuery.find().then((results) => {
    res.success(results);
})
.catch(() =>  {
  response.error("user lookup failed");
});
});
```

I have included only the toUser column in this query

Any idea?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The third line in your code should look like this

friends.equalTo("toUser",{__type:"Pointer", className:"User", objectId:"fEjQgAPvDO"});

- *__type* is always going to be *Pointer*
- *className* is the name of the collection where the objectId is stored. In other words its the 'table' where the Pointer is pointing to
- *objectId* is the ID in that 'table/collection'

Comment: Hi Alon and thank you. Unfortunately, my logic is wrong. Although, maybe with this one I will get the rows, I will not get the friends.With this query, i will take the number of rows where the logged in user has either received or sent a friend request. But i want the opposite, I want the list of his friends

Comment: If you want a list of friends wouldn't you just do this? Parse.Cloud.define('FriendsQuery', function(req,res) {
const friends = new Parse.Query("Friends");
friends.equalTo("toUser",{__type:"Pointer", className:"User", objectId:"fEjQgAPvDO"}); friends.find({sessionToken:request.user.getSessionToken()});

Comment: Yes but maybe the opposite exists, the "fEjQgAPvDO", logged in user, to has sent the request. So I want the fromUser variable.Should I make a second equalto("fromUser", ...)???

Comment: OK so you can do query.equalTo("toUser", request.user); I think that would work (though I haven't tried it)

Comment: yes maybe, but it returns me an empty array..any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The third line should look like this

```
friends.equalTo("toUser", { "__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User", "objectId": "fEjQgAPvDO" })
```